# How to configure a particular GCC cross toolchain in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I have imported some source code as `C++ Makefile Project` to an Eclipse CDT workspace, and specified the `Cross GCC` toolchain for "Indexer Settings":

[image]

The project import went fine, but the include path settings just point to my current native host GCC implementation:

[image]

I've been looking in the `Toolchain Editor` properties dialog, but couldn't find any way to configure a particular cross-toolchain I've been building and installing on my development machine:

[image]

The opened dialog only allows to select the toolchain particles, but not to configure, where these should be actually located:

[image]

---

**How can I configure Eclipse CDT to use my homebrew GCC cross-toolchain to feed the Indexer correctly, and use the standard include paths supplied by my particular GCC cross-toolchain?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *"**How can I configure Eclipse CDT to use my homebrew GCC cross-toolchain to feed the Indexer correctly, and use the standard include paths supplied from this GCC cross-toolchain?**
>   "*

Unfortunately it's not obvious or intuitive, how to set the properties for a particular (cross-)toolchain, that should be bound to a project.

To make these property settings available, first go to the `C++ Build/Builder Settings` Tab in the project properties dialog:

[image]

and check the `Generate Makefiles automatically` option. **Don't click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd> button now!**
But proceed to the `C++ Build->Settings` sub page

[image]

and fill in the cross-toolchain prefix, and path where the binaries are actually located.

Go back to the `C++ Build/Builder Settings` Tab and uncheck the `Generate Makefiles automatically` (to prevent unexpected behavior on automatically started builds) option, before saving the project properties.