# How to get rid of Eclipse indexer "Type std::... could not be resolved" errors in imported make project

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc

Steps to reproduce.

1. Use Linux system where g++ defaults to standard older than c++17, but supports c++17 if given -std option
2. Create trivial C++ project outside of Eclipse with main.cpp:

```
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path p;
    return 0;
}
```

3. And Makefile:

```
all: a.out
a.out: main.cpp
    g++ --std=c++17 -lstdc++fs main.cpp
```

4. Use Eclipse `File->Import->C/C++->Existing Code as Makefile Project` to create project over directory with those 2 files

Project builds properly, but indexer finds unresolved inclusion `filesystem` and type `std::filesystem::path`. In more complicated real world case there were no unresolved inclusions, but a lot of unresolved types were present.

Google finds lots of suggestions to set `-std=c++17` in `Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other Flags` but for imported makefile projects `Tool Settings` are disabled (my Eclipse version was 4.14, but I guess that this is the case for other versions too), sot this is not a way to go.

Comment: What version of g++ do you have?

Comment: You should create Eclipse project instead of writing your own make file. Eclipse requires make file to be generated in a specific way (with options like -MF) in order for indexer to work.

Comment: @NathanOliver
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 8.4.0-3) 8.4.0


Although I don't think this is relevant

Comment: @user7860670
If you have huge existing makefile project and you just want to use Eclipse as nice gdb frontend or refactor tool then you are not really interested in creating "proper" eclipse project, but you may be interested in getting indexer understanding your compilation options

Comment: @Slimak I asked as `filesystem` wasn't supported until GCC8, even though GCC had C++17 support before that.

Comment: I understand your motivation, however this scenario does not seem to be supported properly.

Answer (score 2):

I found partial workaround for projects where you can use same flags for all files in the project. In `Properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Include Paths, Marcos etc.->Providers` tick `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`. This will enable to change contents of field `Command to get compiler specs` which in my case looked by default like this `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`. Add into this command flags you need --- e.g. change it to `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD --std=c++17 "${INPUTS}"`. You may need to restart Eclipse afterwards and/or trigger index rebuild manually.

Contents of this field will be executed **once** with INPUTS replaced by path to an empty `.C` and **once** with an empty `.c` file. Output will be parsed by CDT to understand includes and preprocessor definitions used by your compiler.

If makefile project requires different options for C and C++ this seems to be still achievable but with a bit more work (you need to prepare some script which you will put into this field and this script will need call real compiler with appropriate options depending on language.

It seems that there is no possibility to tell indexer that different files use different options. I tried choosing cross compiler toolchain for indexer while importing project and then using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180772/31086 to select my "fake" tool-chain with empty prefix and path pointing to directory with  scripts `g++`, `gcc` and `as` (which were calling beneath real compiler and logging what is going on), but indexer does not call compiler for each file, it uses its own logic to parse files, so no joy.